# Remove App from Marketplace?

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I'm trying to delist an app I have on the Gsuite marketplace but when I go to https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/mydomainapps it says there are no apps. I've had this app up for about 7 years or so on the marketplace and I know the marketplace has been updated since then. How can I go about removing it if it doesn't show up in my https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/mydomainapps page?

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Delete an App](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6216211?hl=en) support page :

> 1. From the Admin console dashboard, go to Appsand then Marketplace apps.
> 2. Click the app name.
> 3. At the top of the app Settings page, click  Trash icon.
> 4. Click Remove App.
>
> The app and any associated licenses are permanently removed from your
>   domain. The application vendor will delete your data according to the
>   vendor's data retention policy. You may need to repurchase the
>   application if you want to reinstall it. See the vendor's website or
>   Terms of Service for more information.

Comment: Sorry, I probably wasn't clear but I am the vendor. I want to unlist my own app that I have developed. Not just remove someone elses app I installed on my domain. I don't want to delete my app either, I just don't want it to show up publicly. I still want to use it on my own domain.

Answer (score 0):

To unpublish an app from the marketplace:

- In the GCP console, in your project, on the sidebar to the left go to API & Services> Library
- Search for Google Workspace Marketplace SDK, enable and manage
- In there, find Store Listing in the sidebar to the left, and click Unpublish at the bottom